# Using attribute to create an instance of class

Tags: c#, attributes

I have 2 fields like

```
private IFruit fruit;
private Banana banana;
```

An instance of `Banana` is created like this:

```
var banana = new Banana(fruit);
```

I want to create an attribute for `Banana` fields to do the job of creating `Banana` instance for me!

Comment: Google for dependency injection. It does what you are looking for.

Comment: not really clear what you want, sorry. Can you, please, redifine yuor question ?

Comment: You could also look into the [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern. But still your question is not clear enough to give a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes don't cause any code to be executed - you'll have to use reflection to access them. If you want you could implement a base class that has this behavior, and add the reflection code to the constructor:

```
abstract class AutoCreateBase
{
    public MyBase()
    {
        // Reflection to go through the fields, find the attributes, and use Activator.CreateInstance() on each
    }
}

class MyClass : AutoCreateBase
{
    [AutoCreate]
    private Banana banana;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also some container like unity offer this functionality